# Browser Automation Testing with Selenium Web Driver in AWS Code Build

Tags: amazon-web-services, selenium, continuous-integration, aws-codebuild

I want to Automate and integrate the the Selenium web driver tests that we developed for a website in AWS code build environment. We want to run these tests automated, in the AWS Code-Build and then Release (AWS Code-Deploy) if all good.

For example, We wrote all of our test cases using node. Let's assume that I have a basic test case like below

**npm install selenium-webdriver** In a file called **google_test.js**

```
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = webdriver.By,
    until = webdriver.until;

const driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('firefox')
    .build();

driver.get('http://www.google.com');

driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver');

driver.sleep(1000).then(function() {
  driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys(webdriver.Key.TAB);
});

driver.findElement(By.name('btnK')).click();

driver.sleep(2000).then(function() {
  driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
    if(title === 'webdriver - Google Search') {
      console.log('Test passed');
    } else {
      console.log('Test failed');
    }
    driver.quit();
  });
});
```

Then as you would expect We run this test in the command line,

**node google_test**

This works fine and great in a manual environment,

however, our challenge is to automate this and deploy automatically if tests were successful,

I wonder how we can archive this in a the AWS code-build setup. Even after doing all the research Im still confused on what is the best way to achieve this, Many suggests many different ways all looks very hacky and unreliable,

Problems/Questions

1. Since in an Automated AWS code build enr. We dont have browser access, so how can we actually see the output to see if the tests were successful?
2. What is the way/How we can detect the tests ran correctly to proceed to the next step of code-deploy? what signals can be generated and how?
3. If this is not possible, what is the recommended way of doing this?